# How to speed up loading of content from s3

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have hosted a web based application on an EC2 instance. The images are stored in s3. The application will be used across the world. Is there any service in aws/any other way to speed up the distribution of content to the users?

Comment: Is your application currently under-performing from a user perspective? If so, what content is performing poorly — is it the static content from S3, or the HTML page itself from your EC2 server(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to speed up the distribution of content to the users is using “AWS CloudFront” service.

> CloudFront speeds up content delivery by leveraging its global network
>   of data centers, known as edge locations, to reduce delivery time by
>   caching your content close to your end users.

For deployment of CloudFront distribution please refer the below link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/GettingStarted.html

This should help.

Comment: @john, I have static images stored in s3 and it is not loading properly